# How to split the lines in txt into csv in R?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, text, split

I have a `txt` file which a copy of the bills for a patient. I wanted to collect the information about one particular drag which was given to patient from the billing info.

The text file contains all the information about the patient with date, and the bills are listed with respect to the date of purchase(since he is an inward patient, there will more bills).

Now, I have used the following code to extract one particular drag's billing info.

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
data = grep("CAR016", readLines("ip.txt"), value = TRUE)%>% as.data.frame
head(data)
str(data)
```

and the output is the following:

```
> head(data)
                                                                                                                 .
1      4 14/03/2018 CAR016     CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY                 OTH         750.00  1 GEN     750.00 SGET
2      5 15/03/2018 CAR016     CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY                 OTH         750.00  1 GEN     750.00 SGET
3      6 16/03/2018 CAR016     CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY                 OTH         750.00  1 GEN     750.00 SGET
4      7 18/03/2018 CAR016     CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY                 OTH         750.00  1 GEN     750.00 Suji
5    8 19/03/2018 CAR016     CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY                 OTH         750.00  1 GEN     750.00 NISHAN
6       9 20/03/2018 CAR016     CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY                 OTH         750.00  1 GEN     750.00 mam
> str(data)
'data.frame':   38 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ .: Factor w/ 38 levels "   4 14/03/2018 CAR016     CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY                 OTH         750.00  1 GEN     750.00 SGET",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

as one can see, there are 38 lines in the output but it shows only one variable. Now I need to split these lines into columns(10 columns).

### How to do that??

### Update:

I have used the `stringr` package to strip off the while spaces. But after that, I dont know how to proceed to split

### Code:

```
library(readr)
library(stringr)

data = grep("CAR016", readLines("ip.txt"), value = TRUE) 


for (i in seq(1:length(data))) {
  data[i] =  str_replace_all(data[i],pattern='\\s+' , repl=" ")
}

head(data)
```

### Output:

```
> head(data)
[1] " 4 14/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY OTH 750.00 1 GEN 750.00 SGET"  
[2] " 5 15/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY OTH 750.00 1 GEN 750.00 SGET"  
[3] " 6 16/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY OTH 750.00 1 GEN 750.00 SGET"  
[4] " 7 18/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY OTH 750.00 1 GEN 750.00 Suji"  
[5] " 8 19/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY OTH 750.00 1 GEN 750.00 NISHAN"
[6] " 9 20/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY OTH 750.00 1 GEN 750.00 mam"
```

Any hint will be so grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format of the file is `fixed` (as shown in example) then one option could be to use `tidyr::extract` with `regex` to select 10 columns as:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 grep("CAR016", readLines("ip.txt"), value = TRUE)%>% 
 as.data.frame() %>%  # Assuming 10 columns will be part of data
 extract(., ., paste("Col",1:10,sep="_"), 
   regex = "(^\\d+)\\s(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4})\\s([:alnum:]+)\\s+([A-Z :]+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+([0-9.]+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+([:alnum:]+)\\s+([0-9.]+)\\s+(.*$)")
```

Result:

```
#   Col_1      Col_2  Col_3                                     Col_4 Col_5  Col_6 Col_7 Col_8  Col_9 Col_10
# 1     4 14/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY                   OTH 750.00     1   GEN 750.00   SGET
# 2     5 15/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY                   OTH 750.00     1   GEN 750.00   SGET
# 3     6 16/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY                   OTH 750.00     1   GEN 750.00   SGET
# 4     7 18/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY                   OTH 750.00     1   GEN 750.00   Suji
# 5     8 19/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY                   OTH 750.00     1   GEN 750.00 NISHAN
# 6     9 20/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY                   OTH 750.00     1   GEN 750.00    mam
```

**Regex Explanation:**

We need 10 groups to represent 10 columns as expected by `tidyr::extract`.

> ```
> (^\\d+)                 -- Group1 : Start with digits of any size
> \\s                     -- space 
> (\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4})  -- Group2 : Date 
> \\s                     -- space 
> ([:alnum:]+)            -- Group3 : Any number of continuous alpha-numeric
> \\s+                    -- 1+ number of spaces 
> ([A-Z :]+)              -- Group4 : Any number of Character in upper case, : or space
> \\s+                    -- 1+ number of spaces 
> (\\w+)                  -- Group5 : 1+ number of word characters
> \\s+                    -- 1+ number of spaces 
> ([0-9.]+)               -- Group6 : Digits with .
> \\s+
> (\\d+)                  -- Group7 : 1+ digits
> \\s+
> ([:alnum:]+)            -- Group8 : 1+ numbers of continuous alpha-numeric 
> \\s+
> ([0-9.]+)               -- Group9 : Digits with .
> \\s+
> (.*$)                   -- Group10 : Anything left till end character.
> ```

**Edited:** Option#2

Per request from OP, replaced multiple space with single space. Afterwards, one can use `tidyr::separate` (as number of columns are fixed) to split columns on space`(sep = " ")` separator. Finally, one need to `unite` 4th to 8th columns together. The solution will be as:

```
library(tidyverse)


data <- 
  grep("CAR016", readLines("d:\\ip.txt"), value = TRUE)%>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% rename(., V1 = .) %>%
  mutate(V1 = gsub("\\s+", " ",V1)) %>%
  separate("V1", sprintf("Col_%02d",1:14), sep = " ") %>%
  unite(V1_04, c("Col_04", "Col_05",  "Col_06", "Col_07", "Col_08"), sep = " ")
data
#   Col_01     Col_02 Col_03                     V1_04 Col_09 Col_10 Col_11 Col_12 Col_13 Col_14
# 1      4 14/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY    OTH 750.00      1    GEN 750.00   SGET
# 2      5 15/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY    OTH 750.00      1    GEN 750.00   SGET
# 3      6 16/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY    OTH 750.00      1    GEN 750.00   SGET
# 4      7 18/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY    OTH 750.00      1    GEN 750.00   Suji
# 5      8 19/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY    OTH 750.00      1    GEN 750.00 NISHAN
# 6      9 20/03/2018 CAR016 CARDIAC MONITOR : PER DAY    OTH 750.00      1    GEN 750.00    mam
```

Comment: Could you explain the `regrex = ...`?

Comment: However, I could clean the strings to only one white space using the `stringr` package. Thanks for the recommendation. Kindly see the updated question.

Comment: @David I had thought of replace multiple spaces with single space but then your 4th column has got multiple words. Which would have made it divided in many 4 columns. Let me update the answer once you have replaced multiple space with single space.

Comment: @David I have updated the answer. You can use either of the method. I'm not sure why 1st method is not working for you. Perhaps you should have tried with the sample data provided by you ( I mean only 6 rows).

Comment: Is the package `splitstackshape` not available for R 3.4.4?? I could not install the package itself. Infact I expect the solution, if possible, not adding that package.

Comment: @David Since, you got predefined sets of column in your data, you can even use `tidyr::separate`. I have updated my option#2 accordingly. Have a look.

Comment: Works perfectly..Thanks